# update items (SingleChoiceItems) of a Dialog Alert

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have Dialog Alert like below

[image: Dialog Alert]

When I close it and then update it's items `String Array`,
after I open it again, I see the older `Dialog` like picture above and
nothings changed. What's the problem?

this is code of calling Alert Dialog

```
 public void onClickSafheMojud(View view){
    item=null;
    Cursor cursor=dbAdapter.getAllData();
    int i=0;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        i=1;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){

            i++;
        }
    }
    if(i>0) {
        CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[i];

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            items[0] = cursor.getString(0);
            i = 1;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                items[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                i++;
            }
        }
        item=items;
        showDialog(0);
    }
    else


}
```

and here is Dialog Alert Builder

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    switch (id){
        case 0:

AlertDialog.Builder builder2=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder2.setIcon(R.drawable.res);
            builder2.setTitle("انتخاب کنید");
            builder2.setPositiveButton("برو", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                }
            });
            builder2.setNegativeButton("لغو", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "لغو شد.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            builder2.setSingleChoiceItems(item, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    kodam_safhe=which;
                }
            });
            kodam_safhe=0;
            return builder2.create();


 return null;
}
```

Comment: Include your code for the Alert Dialog

Comment: I don't use adapter. just pass a string array to builder.setSingleChoiceItems(String array,listener)

Comment: Show us your code. How are you setting the adapter and how are you updating it's array? etc

Comment: actually update the array with new data from database and then click on button to create Dialog again

Answer (score 0):

Take on globel `int` variable.

```
int test = 0;
```

And `setSingleChoiceItems` like this

```
builder2.setSingleChoiceItems(item, test, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    test = which;
                }
            });
```

Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

After Days I found the answer
the Problem is : use of onCreateDialog and Override it
I just create a AlertDialog.Builder and then show it
I don't use showDialog() method
items update every time